# How to I add a header to a tsv in python?

Tags: python, database, csv, datatables, header

```
persons = [
    {"name":"howard", "adress":"New Jersey", "blood group":"AB"},
    {"name":"harry", "adress":"New York", "blood group":"O"},

]

output_file = "outputfile.tsv"
with open(outfilename, "w") as output:    

    for row in persons:
        column_values = row.values()
        line = "\t".join(column_values) + '\n'
        output.write(line)
```

I tried using methods for csv but it didnt work furthermore I tried changing the dictionary but was not succesufull

Comment: Can you use the `csv` module? If not, you probably want to test if row is the "first" row and write `row.keys()`

Comment: how can i test if row is the first row?

Comment: `enumerate(persons)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. In particular `csv.DictWriter()`. It can add the header using the `dict` keys as the field names and `writeheader()` to create the header. Then you write out the data using `writerows()`.

```
import csv

persons = [
    {"name":"howard", "adress":"New Jersey", "blood group":"AB"},
    {"name":"harry", "adress":"New York", "blood group":"O"},

]

output_file = "outputfile.tsv"

with open(output_file, 'w') as csv_file:
    hdr = persons[0].keys()
    csvDictR = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, hdr, delimiter='\t')
    csvDictR.writeheader()
    csvDictR.writerows(persons)

cat outputfile.tsv
name    adress  blood group
howard  New Jersey      AB
harry   New York        O
```